# Google Speech Recognition API for Android is totally free in offline mode, without restriction?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm developing an application that requires the passage of speech to text and for that I'm using the Google Speech Recognition API for Android. But I have a question, in **offline mode** (I don't want to use it online), does it have a limit of use simply to capture voice, without restriction? NO orders like "Ok Google", voice only. I searched all over the Internet but I'm not 100% sure.

Can you help me? Thank you all.

Comment: There are no limits on the native offline recognition supplied by Google Now/Assistant